# PhoneGap: Error on phonegap run android

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, web

I'm trying to run

```
phonegap run android --device={device id here}
```

but everytime I try to run the phonegap application the following takes place:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/lightshire/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

My paths are completely set

- adb
- ant
- fastboot
- java

are all working

I ran `echo $PATH` and got the following

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/lightshire/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/home/lightshire/ant/bin
```

I also updated the android API, I figured out that the problem would be my device since its 2.3 so I downloaded all the android API including 2.3 to 4.4 but I still got the same error. I'm actually stumped on what the problem might be.

Comment: try removing the platforms/android folder and then run "phonegap -V build android"

Answer (score 0):

Did you set all paths are correctly?

```
E:\ant\bin;                            -ant path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin; -java path
E:\Node;                               -Node path
E:\Eclipse\sdk\platform-tools;         -SDK platform tool path
E:\Eclipse\sdk\tools;                  -SDK tool path
C:\Users\Account\Account\Roaming\npm;  -npm path
```

Comment: did you not see i already echo'd my $PATH and shown it to my question.

The paths are correct.

BTW. im in linux not in windows